# Insert NSMutableDictionary with NSDictionaries

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I tried to insert `NSDictionary`'s in a `NSMutableDictionary`. There is no error but it won't work, it remains empty.

Here's my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary *einnahmen = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
            name, 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: x], 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: y], 
            [NSNumber numberWithInt: z], 
            nil];
NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                     @"name", 
                     @"startJahr",
                     @"zins", 
                     @"entnahmefaehig",
                     nil];
NSDictionary *entry = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];

[einnahmen setObject:entry forKey:@"name"]; //seems not to work
```

After `[einnahmen setObject:entry` the Debugger shows this:

[image]

Comment: Your code references the nonexistent variables `einnahmen` and `eintrag` in the line that you say does not work. This is impossible to debug. Also, "seems not to work" is extremely vague. What happens that makes you think it doesn't work? Does the wrong thing get inserted? Do you get an error? Does the program crash and redirect the user's computer to porn site?

Comment: Is 'einnahem' supposed to be 'entry'?  Even if so, setObject will add a new value to the dictionary; how do you know it's not working?  Possibly einnahem is nil?  Also, you are using 'name' as an object at first and later as a key.

Comment: You still don't show where `einnahmen` is created and accessed to check its contents. This is crucial.

Comment: I added the initialization of einnahmen in my posted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem. The following code was in the wrong init-method:

```
NSMutableDictionary *einnahmen = 
              [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
```

The compiler should show a error.